# Multiplication using add and shift: translating from Java to MIPS

Tags: java, assembly, mips, multiplication

I have to write in MIPS a program that multiplies two number using the add and shift method.  After trying many many times, I got somehow a program that I see to should be working, but its not, then I wrote it in Java and the code worked in Java.  Then I tried to convert it from Java to MIPS (usually its easier for me to translate to low level language from a code in high level language), and after translating it, still its not working. Here is the code I wrote, and please if anybody detects anything wrong with them or knows how to fix them please do tell me.

Thanks,

In Java:

```
static int prod = 0;

public static int mult (int mcand, int mier)
{
    while (mier != 0)
    {
        int rem = mier % 2;

        if (rem != 0)
        {
            prod += mcand;
        }

        mcand = mcand << 1;
        mier = mier >> 1;
    }

    return prod;
}
```

In MIPS:

```
# A program that multiplies two integers using the add and shift method

.data # Data declaration section

.text

main: # Start of code section

    li $s0, 72 # the multiplicand
    li $t0, 72 # the multiplicand in a temporary register
    li $s1, 4 # the multiplier
    li $t1, 4 # the multiplier in a temporary register
    li $s2, 0 # the product
    li $s3, 2 # the number 2 in a register for dividing by 2 always for checking if even or odd

LOOP: # first we check if the multiplier is zero or not

    beq $t1, $zero, END

    div $t1, $s3
    mfhi $t3 # remainder is now in register $t3

    beq $t3, $zero, CONTINUE # if the current digit is 0, then no need to add just go the shifting part

    add $s2, $s2, $t0 # the adding of the multiplicand to the product

CONTINUE: # to do the shifting after either adding or not the multiplicand to the product
    sll $t0, $t0, 1
    srl $t0, $t0, 1

    j LOOP # to jump back to the start of the loop

END:    
    add $a0, $a0, $s2
    li $v0, 1
    syscall

# END OF PROGRAM
```

---

Comment: Since noone has mentioned that before: Optimize out the divide. In a nutshell modulo 2 is equivalent to "andi register, 1" (sorry, my MIPS skills are rusty these days)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aside from @Joop Eggen's correction, you have to take into account whether delay branching takes into place or not.
If the MIPS you are using has delay branching you should modify your program accordingly. The simplest way is to add a `nop` instruction after your jumps/branches (after the two `beq` and after `j`).

Besides that, at the end of your code you are adding the result ($s2) to $a0 instead of moving it there.

So, to summarize:

- take into account delay branching, i.e. add `nop` after beq's and j
- change `srl $t0, $t0`, 1 to `srl $t1, $t1, 1`
- change `add $a0, $a0`, $s2 to `add $a0, $0, $s2`

Comment: Well, thnx very much gusbro, it worked.
But I have one question, what is delay branching? And what use if the nop useful for?

Comment: Delay branching is when the processor will execute the next instruction after a branch even if the branch takes place. The nop is a NO-OP instruction (has no effect, just consumes time). When you have delay branching and do not want to bother optimizing your code then the easiest way is to add a `nop` after every branch/jump instruction.

Comment: Ohh, I see.
If I put the nop instruction after every branch and jump, even if there was no delay branching, will it take effect of it will be the same as not putting it?

Comment: If you put the `nop` after every branch and there is not delayed branching then the `nop` will not be executed when the branch takes places, and when the branch does not take place then it will be executed but it won't have any effect (apart from the time consumed to execute it).

Comment: Okay, well thnx very much for the help gusbro

Answer (score 3):

Copy error on srl at the end:

```
srl $t1, $t1, 1
```

Comment: ohh yeh, sorry this is a typo

Answer (score 0):

A program that multiplies two integers using the add and shift method:

```
.data # Data declaration section

.text

main: # Start of code section

    li $s0, 72 # the multiplicand
    li $t0, 72 # the multiplicand in a temporary register
    li $s1, 4 # the multiplier
    li $t1, 4 # the multiplier in a temporary register
    li $s2, 0 # the product
    li $s3, 2 # the number 2 in a register for dividing by 2 always for checking if even or odd

LOOP: # first we check if the multiplier is zero or not

    beq nop $t1, $zero, END

    div $t1, $s3
    mfhi $t3 # remainder is now in register $t3

    beq nop $t3, $zero, CONTINUE # if the current digit is 0, then no need to add just go the shifting part

    add $s2, $s2, $t0 # the adding of the multiplicand to the product

CONTINUE: # to do the shifting after either adding or not the multiplicand to the product
    sll $t0, $t0, 1
    srl $t1, $t1, 1

    j nop LOOP # to jump back to the start of the loop

END:    
    add $a0, $0, $s2
    li $v0, 1
    syscall
```